# How to use delegate data in a Getter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I have been rattling this around my head for a few hours now.  I am trying create a `UserProfileViewController` that will handle likes, bookmarks, etc on my app.  It will receive an access_token from a child Controller: `LoginViewController`

I have the `LoginViewController` working.  It launches a UIWebView to a remote system.  The remote system handles login and receives an access_token which is the user's ID.

I have set up a delegate in my `LoginViewController` to pass back the data, but I think I want the value in a Getter in the `UserProfileViewController`.

Here is how I imagine the UserProfileViewController.m would look, but obviously it won't work:

```
@synthesize access_token = _access_token;

- (NSString *) access_token  // Getter
{
    if(!_access_token)
    {
        _access_token= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"access_token"];
        if (!_access_token)
        {
            LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
            loginViewController.delegate = self;

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginViewController animated:YES];
            // I need the access_token here but it won't arrive until delegate_AccessToken is called by LoginViewController
        }
    }
    return _access_token;
}

// received from LoginViewController
- (void) delegate_AccessToken: (NSString *) aAccess_token
{
    // now it's too late to use this in the Getter
}


- (IBOutlet *) likes: (id) sender
{
    [self likeThis: sender access_token: _access_token];
}
```

When is a good time to call `LoginViewController` to get the access_token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good pattern for this is for the `UserProfileViewController` to call the `LoginViewController` as soon as it can, for example in the `viewDidLoad`, and while the delegate did not return with the information you will present no data in the  `UserProfileViewController`, you may present a loading hud that tells the user to please load while getting the access token

Comment: Thanks!  This is a good solution.  Here's a follow up question.  What if UserProfileViewController doesn't have a view except for when it calling LoginViewController?  In other words, if likes: wasn't an IBOutlet but was going to be called by a parent ViewController?  Ie: Another Controller calls: [[[UserProfileViewController alloc] init] likes: @"something to like"];  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly your flow, it does not make sense to let a user be in UserProfileViewController if it is not logged in (in other words, you don't have a profile unless you are logged in).
So what I would do is:

- Force the user to log in first pushing LoginViewController from your ParentViewController.
  Store that in NSUSerDefaults within the LoginViewController class and then push your UserProfileViewController.
- If for some reason a timeout happen, and your access_token is not longer valid, you should use NSNotifications to perform a log out operation (pushing the LogInViewController again from whatever ViewController you are in the app).

Post a notification when the time-out happen:

```
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"performLogOut"
                                  object:nil
                                userInfo:nil];
```

Make every ViewController that depends on that token a listener:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(performLogOut)
                                             name:@"logOut"
                                           object:nil];
```

Finally, implement performLogOut in all the ViewController that are listening and push the LogInViewController in there to force the user login.

Hope this helps!